# Spring 4 Restfull Service with bean

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a simple Server / Client application that can send a bean as parameter instead of String but failing  below is my code

Server

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/returnGreet")
public @ResponseBody Greeting returnGreet(
        @RequestBody(required=false) Greeting greet) {
    if(greet == null)
          return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                  String.format(template, greet));
    else
        return new Greeting(0,"Testing");
}
}
```

Client

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    MultiValueMap<String,Greeting> greet = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Greeting>();
    greet.add("greet", new Greeting(0,"XOXO"));



    greeting = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/returnGreet",greet, Greeting.class,greet);
    System.out.println("Content:    " + greeting.getContent());
    System.out.println("Id:   " + greeting.getId() );
```

The result is always null for the object greet at the server side.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the `RestTemplate` correctly. Why are you passing a `MultiValueMap` as the Entity to be sent? This won't get serialized the way your Server expects.

Just use the `Greeting` object directly.

```
restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/returnGreet", new Greeting(0, "XOXO"), Greeting.class);
```

Also, the last argument is not necessary, you don't have any URI variables.

Comment: I am already done that but i am getting error org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request  , i don't how to trace it more .

Comment: @Shahbour Set your server's logger level to DEBUG and check where Spring fails to deserialize the body.

Comment: Hello , it worked now the missing also was that the class Greeting did not have empty Constructor which is required , i found out that after changing the log to TRACE for <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc" level="TRACE" />   . Great

Comment: @Shahbour Glad to hear it. Note that the no-arg constructor isn't necessarily required if you annotated the parameters with `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: thanks for your help . Is it possible to annotate two variables with `@RequestBody` , in case we got a method that accept two parameters , or this obey Rest rules ?

Comment: @Shahbour That doesn't have anything to do with Rest really. What kind of request body are you sending that would map better to two object rather than a single one.

Comment: I don't have any thing in mind , just thinking if that is possible , then how to handle it in restTemplate or i have to create a wrapper object for both.

Comment: @Shahbour I would create a wrapper.